# How can I implement smart contracts with my private blockchain?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I have some IoT(Internet of things) nodes sharing the received data from sensors with each others. I partitioned them to 2 private(permissioned) networks:

Network 1 includes: X,Y,Z nodes trusting each other. 
Network 2 includes: M,N,O nodes trusting each other,for example.

In addition to overall smart contract for each network,

Can I write an individual contract which is special for each node of network( a smart contract for each node) for doing particular act in special time, such as sending data to the another node of another network in special time?

For instance, a particular smart contract for node X of network 1 that in special time is triggered to send data to node M of network 2.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, a particular smart contract for node X of network 1 that
>   in special time is triggered to send data to node M of network 2.

I don't think it's possible for a contract function to be directly triggered by a time event. Instead you would need an external application to call the contract's function at the specified time. Check out [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time) for more info.

I also don't think it's possible for a contract to send data to a different network without an external application.

Comment: I would like to store an dynamic array including a number of times such as 8 am and 2 pm in a smart contract (each node has its own separate smart contract).  At these times, smart contract itself or call a component of node for reading some data from blockchain and then send to a node in second network. 2) while updating an array of a smart contract later, whether smart contract is able to check the identity(PK) of a person or machine with right to update the times of array before updating?

Comment: Can I also define an overall smart contract including an array containing the PK of nodes wich are the member of permissioned network. Each node can read these PKs from smart contract and then store in its own storage and accept only data sent by a node of this PK list. This array will be updated later that announces to aIl member nodes for updating their PK list from smart contract since a new node might be added or eliminated to/from network.            
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60462/smart-contract-and-permissioned-blockchain?rq=1

Comment: It's common for a contract to have an owner account with permission to call admin functions. For your contract I imagine the owner would add PK accounts to the contract and assign permissions to each PK. Check out [this section on restricting access](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/common-patterns.html#restricting-access) for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your great response. Would you answer my first comment(I would like to store an dynamic array including a number of times such as 8 am and 2 pm in a smart contract (each node has its own separate smart contract). At these times,....)?

Comment: I don't understand why each node has its own contract... But [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12097/creating-dynamic-arrays) gives an example of how a contract could assign arrays to each PK account. You'll probably want to restrict the append function to the owner and/or the PK accounts (as described in my previous comment). Also it might be useful to add an address parameter to the append function, rather than automatically using the sender's address.

Comment: As I told, for example, Network 1 includes: X,Y,Z nodes and Network 2 includes: M,N,O nodes. Node X depending on existing times and their target nodes in its own contract reads data from BC and send data. For instance, in smart contract of node X:  2pm, send latest block to node M of network 2. in smart contract of node Y: 8 am send latest data received from sensor 1(stored in BC of network 1) to node N of network 2. Can I write such a smart contract special for each node?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for contracts to communicate directly to an outside network. You would need an external relay... Is this something that already exists? I still don't understand the point of two networks and six contracts. It seems much simpler to have one network and one contract that handles the owner and six nodes...

Comment: I appreciate your response and attention. Due to character limitation, I wrote in this link: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60890/smart-contract-and-2-permissioned-blockchain-networks                 please answer it.

Comment: Dear sfmiller940, I was appreciate if you could answer my top link comment related to your last comment.